# Is it possible to pull the content from the title tag and display it as text on a html webpage? Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, page-title

I'm in the process of making a site that has a lot of different URL's all sharing the same design. I'm trying to make the titles display on each site because they're all unique, where as everything else is the same for the most part. I tried using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  document.write(document.referrer);
// -->
</script>
```

On some browsers this would display the URL at the bottom of the webpage, but on others it wouldn't show at all, I tried to grab the data from this and move it to where I would like the content to go but I wasn't able to select it at all.

I'm using wordpress as my CMS and I looked into the editor to see if there was something I could do there and realized its all php - something I've never used before. I searched if there was a way to do this in wordpress but turned up with nothing.

I'm assuming this is where the php code should be

```
<h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">here</a></h1>
```

I'm assuming I'd need something similar to the php echo in the href where it says 'here'. Just to try I put the script in the anchor tag and not surprisingly the whole site stopped working because of an error. So I'm stuck.

Is there a way in wordpress that I can pull the title tag from the header into the html?

Comment: could you use wordpress built-in functions like the_title() and the_permalink() to get the title and the url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple script to get the `title` of the page.

```
var title = $("title").text();
$("body").html("<h1>" + title + "</h1>");
```

The first line is getting the `text` portion of the `title` tag. The second line just replaces all the contents of your `body` tag to only contain the `title` extracted. Modify the second line to fit what you need. The important part you need to know is the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript)

> To get the path, you can use:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL
```

Comment: Thats for the URL though, I'm looking for the title tag if possible ... I did try this but it would display the main url only (the one the redirects were coming from), didn't matter that the URL of the site was different

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current page title use

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

Or if you want the meta title use

```
<?php wp_title(); ?>
```

They're both WordPress PHP functions.

Assuming you want the meta title (from the header) use

```
<h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php wp_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

Here's the docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey thanks! the first one did pull the content of the current page title, but the meta title didn't display anything at all unfortunately

Comment: On the homepage it doesn't show anything, what is it you're wanting pulled through? <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> will display the site title set in the WordPress admin settings. It's best to use PHP as not all site visitors will have JavaScript enabled and so it the other answers unfortunately won't always work.

Comment: This is really informative https://perishablepress.com/how-to-generate-perfect-wordpress-title-tags-without-a-plugin/